# How to get facebook ad statistics in utc

Tags: facebook, api, timezone, stat

Is there a way to get ad statistics for a utc time, it seems like the returned stats are aligned to the ad account time zone.
We tried to defined utc time zone for the ad account but we didn't found any country that match utc time (we assume that it related to daylight saving).

Answer (score 0):

No, the stats must be retrieved for 24 hour (or multiples of 24 hours) periods in the Ad Account's timezones. If you were checking the stats hourly and storing them hourly you could calculate the stats for an arbitrary timezone, but the API will always respond with the stats in the timezone of the account